# synchronize date in apache storm cluster

Tags: apache-storm

I use an apache storm topology on a cluster of 8+1 machines. The date on these machines is not the same and we may have more than 5 minutes of difference.

```
preprod-storm-nimbus-01:
    Thu Feb 25 16:20:30 GMT 2016
preprod-storm-supervisor-01:
    Thu Feb 25 16:20:32 GMT 2016
preprod-storm-supervisor-02:
    Thu Feb 25 16:20:32 GMT 2016
preprod-storm-supervisor-03:
    Thu Feb 25 16:14:54 UTC 2016     <<-- this machine is very late :(
preprod-storm-supervisor-04:
    Thu Feb 25 16:20:31 GMT 2016
preprod-storm-supervisor-05:
    Thu Feb 25 16:20:17 GMT 2016
preprod-storm-supervisor-06:
    Thu Feb 25 16:20:00 GMT 2016
preprod-storm-supervisor-07:
    Thu Feb 25 16:20:31 GMT 2016
preprod-storm-supervisor-08:
    Thu Feb 25 16:19:55 GMT 2016
preprod-storm-supervisor-09:
    Thu Feb 25 16:20:30 GMT 2016
```

Question:
**Is the storm topology affected by this non-synchronization?**

Note: I know that synchronizing is better, but the sysadmins won't do it without proving them proofs/reasons that they *have to* do it. Do they really have to do it, "for the topology's sake" :) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the computation you are doing... It might have an effect on your result if you do time based window operations. Otherwise, it doesn't matter.

For Storm as an execution engine it has no effect at all.